# Git error can't push 'Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.'

Tags: git, github

I was added as a collaborator to a **private** github project of an organisation. I tried to open the repo link on the browser and it opens, so I must have access to the repo, right?

I tried the `git clone` operation via SSH and was successful.

I init git, and checked all the branches. There were all the local branches as well as the remote branches. I checked `git remote -v` and it has all the correct ssh urls for the project (for push and fetch) as origin.

However, after creating a new branch called `test` and then trying to `git push origin test`, I was hit by this error message:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried doing the `ssh -T git@github.com` and it gives me this message:

```
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

So this means I'm authenticated, and that username is the same username (account) as the one I'm running on the browser, and as I said above, I can visit the repo on the web, I can clone, yet I can't push to it.

I've tried creating a new ssh key, but nothing seems to change. Can this be the fault of the repo owner (not giving me the right access or smth)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging into to the GitHub with org SSO then you need to enable SSO for your git which would be under profile > security > enable SSO

Comment: I don't see this 'enable sso' under security. :/

Comment: Please follow the steps: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/authorizing-an-ssh-key-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on

Comment: None of my ssh keys have the 'enable sso' dropdown. Each of them only has a delete button.

Comment: Then, it is an write permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning https not into ssh, make sure you have the correct username and do check the git config properly

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is the [Github status page](https://www.githubstatus.com/) as this happened to me just now.